# Is there a way to make this dropdown appear like a table?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, nav

I am trying to fix this navigation. I want to make the dropdown on Animals (Alpacas, Buffalo, etc) to be split into 2 or 3 sections so the list will not be so long.

Here is the code:

```css
@charset "utf-8";
body {
  font: 100%/1.4 Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: #4E5869;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #000;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1260px;
  /* a max-width may be desirable to keep this layout from getting too wide on a large monitor. This keeps line length more readable. IE6 does not respect this declaration. */
  min-width: 480px;
  /* a min-width may be desirable to keep this layout from getting too narrow. This keeps line length more readable in the side columns. IE6 does not respect this declaration. */
  background: #FFF;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* the auto value on the sides, coupled with the width, centers the layout. It is not needed if you set the .container's width to 100%. */
}


/*First remove all default margins and padding*/

nav,
ul,
li,
a {
  padding: 0 0;
  margin: 0 0
}

nav.navigate5 {
  width: 100%;
  padding: .5% 0;
  background: #66e0ff;
  float: left
}


/*  hnavbar  */

ul.hnavbar5 {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  /* Clear floats */
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
}

ul.hnavbar5 li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

ul.hnavbar5 a {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #f2f2f2 !important;
  background: #00ccff;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #000000;
}

ul.hnavbar5 a:hover {
  color: white !important;
  background: #00ccff;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 6px #000000 inset;
}


/*--- DROPDOWN ---*/

ul.hnavbar5 ul,
ul.hnavbar5 li:hover ul li ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

ul.hnavbar5 ul li {
  padding-top: 0px;
  float: none;
}

ul.hnavbar5 ul a {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

ul.hnavbar5 li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

ul.hnavbar5 li ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  z-index: 10
}

ul.hnavbar5 li:hover a {
  background: #00ccff !important;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul.hnavbar5 li:hover ul a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul.hnavbar5 li:hover ul li a:hover {
  background: #00ccff !important;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 6px #000000 inset;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  <link href="style2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <nav class="navigate5">
      <ul class="hnavbar5">
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Main Pages</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="animals.php">Animals</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="alpacas.php">Alpacas</a></li>
                <li><a href="buffalo.php">Buffalo</a></li>
                <li><a href="chickens.php">Chickens</a></li>
                <li><a href="chinchillas.php">Chinchillas</a></li>
                <li><a href="cows.php">Cows</a></li>
                <li><a href="deer.php">Deer</a></li>
                <li><a href="donkeys.php">Donkeys</a></li>
                <li><a href="ducks.php">Ducks</a></li>
                <li><a href="elk.php">Elk</a></li>
                <li><a href="ferrets.php">Ferrets</a></li>
                <li><a href="geese.php">Geese</a></li>
                <li><a href="goats.php">Goats</a></li>
                <li><a href="guinea_pigs.php">Guinea Pigs</a></li>
                <li><a href="guineafowl.php">Guineafowl</a></li>
                <li><a href="hedgehogs.php">Hedgehogs</a></li>
                <li><a href="helpers.php">Helpers</a></li>
                <li><a href="horses.php">Horses</a></li>
                <li><a href="ostriches.php">Ostriches</a></li>
                <li><a href="otters.php">Otters</a></li>
                <li><a href="peacocks.php">Peacocks</a></li>
                <li><a href="pheasants.php">Pheasants</a></li>
                <li><a href="pigs.php">Pigs</a></li>
                <li><a href="rabbits.php">Rabbits</a></li>
                <li><a href="rams.php">Rams</a></li>
                <li><a href="sheep.php">Sheep</a></li>
                <li><a href="swans.php">Swans</a></li>
                <li><a href="turkeys.php">Turkeys</a></li>
                <li><a href="turtles.php">Turtles</a></li>
                <li><a href="yak.php">Yak</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="certificates.php">Certificates</a></li>
            <li><a href="consumables.php">Consumables</a></li>
            <li><a href="crops.php">Crops and Produce</a></li>
            <li><a href="deco.php">Decorations</a></li>
            <li><a href="farm_upgrades.php">Farm Upgrades</a></li>
            <li><a href="outfits.php">Outfits</a></li>
            <li><a href="trees.php">Trees</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="flower_trees.php">Flower Trees</a></li>
                <li><a href="fruit_trees.php">Fruit Trees</a></li>
                <li><a href="nut_trees.php">Nut Trees</a></li>
                <li><a href="other_trees.php">Other Trees</a></li>
                <li><a href="special_trees.php">Special Trees</a></li>
                <li><a href="wood_trees.php">Wood Trees</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="themes.html">Themes</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Crafted Items</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="all.php">All Crafting Buildings</a></li>
            <li><a href="kiln.php">Kiln Only</a></li>
            <li><a href="kitchen.php">Kitchen Only</a></li>
            <li><a href="workshop.php">Workshop Only</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Indexes</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="alphabetical.php">Alphabetical Index</a></li>
            <li><a href="reverse.php">Reverse Lookup</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

What I would like to do is keep this design, but make the animals section drop down into 2 or 3 columns so it won't be so long. Right now it is very long. I am not sure if this will make a difference, but this nav will be on a php page.

The current layout can be seen [here](https://fv2cheats.rainbow-solutions.tech/test/testnav.php).

Just a note, this is just a temp site created to fix the issue without interrupting the site that will be using it.

Comment: When the `li` is hovered set the `ul` to `display:flex;flex-wrap:wrap;`
    and a minimum width of about `200px` maybe more depends on how you like it and also `flex:1` on the `li` children of the `ul` [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/nyect82q/)

Comment: @ZohirSalak, assuming I have what you are saying in the correct places, this works to a point, but I was looking more for a box with the two columns and the buttons in the dropdown for animals so that the columns were a bit more even. This way looks messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just create a specific css for that:

```
ul.cols-2 {
  columns: 2;
  column-gap: .1em;
}
```

and add this class like this:

```
<ul class="cols-2" >
  <li><a href="alpacas.php">Alpacas</a></li>
  <li><a href="buffalo.php">Buffalo</a></li>
  <li><a href="chickens.php">Chickens</a></li>
...
```

Comment: This one worked almost perfectly. Thank you. I just changed the columns to 3 instead because 2 cut part of one of the buttons off and put it on the top of the second columns splitting that button.